# Retrieving data to build and schedule parallel Airflow operators

Tags: mongodb, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have an Airflow application that runs a model for a number of entities.

Initially, the model ran as three stages of an Airflow DAG, where each stage calculated attributes for each entity serially. That is, the first stage calculated some attributes for each of ~200 entities, and the next stage calculated different attributes for those ~200 entities, etc. Each stage was a separate python operator. Entity identities and attributes are stored in a MongoDB database using several collections per entity. The serial implementation took ~12 hours to run and was not performant.

I was able to rearchitect the application by adding a single MongoDB query to the DAG to retrieve entity IDs and schedule ~200 "chains" of the three stages. That allowed me to bring the execution time down to 2.5 hours. I would like to parallelize further, by running each entity down into several subentities by date range. But when I try to loop through the ~200 entities and query date ranges for each entity the DAG can't be loaded and times out. I wasn't surprised, as Airflow best practices warn against database queries in a DAG.

Alternatively, I wanted to place an operator that ran the MongoDB queries and either passed a dictionary back to the DAG or stored the dictionary in an XCom. But there doesn't appear to be a way for a DAG to retrieve items in an XCom.
Does anyone know how to query a database for values that are used to create multiple DAGs or to pass data from a DAG task back to the calling DAG?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have quite a good overview published recently on how to deal with Dynamic DAG generation.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dynamic-dag-generation

It's been published couple of days ago, so you might not have seen it yet (and maybe you even have to shift-refresh that page :D)

I think your best bet will be to have a separate script that exports result of your query to a json/yaml file that is located in the "dag" directory and then the DAG could read and use that file to create DAGs.

This is described here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dynamic-dags-with-external-configuration-from-a-structured-data-file

Also - maybe a better solution will be to generate a Python file with the data embedded https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#generating-python-code-with-embedded-meta-data in similar way (rather than .yaml or .json). This has some advantages as easier reusability and import accross multiple DAG files if you are ok with generating Python rather than structured yaml/json (I'd actually recommend that one as it is more Pythonic approach).